# Get text from list

Tags: list, sharepoint-server

I am not able to get text from sharepoint list fields. I have created list with column Name, Email but cannot get text. Now i can get attachment url but not the contents inside those columns

```
var customlist;
var allItems;
var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
debugger;
var web = context.get_web();
var list = web.get_lists().getByTitle("Mylist");

var query = new SP.CamlQuery(); //The Query object. This is used to query for data in the List

query.set_viewXml('<View><RowLimit></RowLimit>3</View>');
allItems = list.getItems(query);


context.load(allItems, 'Include(AttachmentFiles)'); //Retrieves the properties of a client object from the server.


//context.load(this.customlist, 'Include(AttachmentFiles)'); //Retrieves the properties of a client object from the server.
//context.load(items);

//Execute the Query Asynchronously
context.executeQueryAsync(
    Function.createDelegate(this, function () {
        var enumerator = allItems.getEnumerator();
        while (enumerator.moveNext()) {
            var currentListItem = enumerator.get_current();
           var fieldText = currentListItem.get_item('Name');
            var attachments = currentListItem.get_attachmentFiles();
            for (var j = 0; j < attachments.get_count() ; j++) {
                attachment = attachments.getItemAtIndex(j);
                console.log(attachment.get_serverRelativeUrl());
            }
        }
               }),
    Function.createDelegate(this, fail)
);

function fail() {
    debugger;
    alert(arguments[1].get_message());
}
```

I get error on this line

```
var fieldText = currentListItem.get_item('Name');
```

The error is `The property or field has not been initialized. It has not been requested or the request has not been executed. It may need to be explicitly requested.`

What is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Ok i managed to solve. It looks like i have to include field names. I was only including attachment. So i changed code from

```
 context.load(allItems, 'Include(AttachmentFiles)'); //Retrieves the properties of a client object from the server.
```

To

```
 context.load(allItems, 'Include(AttachmentFiles,Name,Email)'); //Retrieves the properties of a client object from the server.
```